# Is weighted average always smaller or equal than arithmetic average?

Tags: statistics, inequality, average

Is a weighted average, assuming the weights sum up to one, always smaller than the unweighted arithmetic average? As if the weights are smaller than one the weighted mean is a convex combination of the individual points. Is there any condition on the individual observation for the statement to hold true? Would be great if you could provide a mathematical proof. Thank you!

Comment: It depends how you weight. If you place high weight on low values, the arithmetic average could be higher. E.g. if $$x_1 = 100,x_2 = 1, w_1 = 0.01, w_2 = 0.99,$$ you can see that $$w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 < \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}.$$

Comment: Consider the numbers $(0,2)$. Their average is $1$. Now put weights $(1000,1)$ for them and the weighted average becomes $\frac{0+2}{1000+1} = \frac{2}{1001}$. This is smaller than the arithmetic average. Then consider the opposite weights, $(1,1000)$. Now the weighted average is $\frac{0+2000}{1+1000} = \frac{2000}{1001}\approx 2$. This is larger than the arithmetic average.

Comment: I realised you were effectively asking for a case where weighted average was $\ge $ the unweighted average. In that case, you can swap the two weights in my example above.

Comment: It doesn't take long to find a counterexample!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normally true, as examples in the comments show. However, there is a natural condition which will make it true: the condition that the weights are in the opposite order to the numbers, i.e. smaller numbers get larger weights. This then follows from [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

More generally, if weights and numbers are negatively correlated then the weighted mean will be less than the arithmetic mean. However, this is not a very deep statement, since that is basically how "negatively correlated" is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can work it out:
$$\begin{align}\text{WM} \ &\lor \ \text{AM}\\
\frac{w_1x_1+w_2x_2}{w_1+w_2} \ &\lor \ \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \iff\\
\frac{w_1x_1+(1-w_1)x_2}{1} \ &\lor \ \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \iff\\
2w_1x_1+2(1-w_1)x_2 \ &\lor \ x_1+x_2 \iff\\
(2w_1-1)(x_1-x_2) \ &\lor \ \ 0 \end{align}$$
Now, you have various options. For example, if $w_1>\frac12, x_1>x_2$, then WM>AM.

Answer (score 0):

$$0.9\times1+0.1\times3<0.5\times1+0.5\times3$$ because more emphasis is given to the smaller value. But
$$0.1\times1+0.9\times3>0.5\times1+0.5\times3.$$

---

The range of values that can be reached by a weighted average is the whole interval from the smallest to the largest value. The arithmetic average is perforce in between.

---

There is no simple general condition for a weighted average to be smaller than the arithmetic average.